# October CMS relationships

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have 3 models.

`Quote`
`Status`
`Event`

1 `Quote` belongs to 1 `Status` and 1 `Event`.
However `Status` and `Event` can have many `Quote`.

How do i set this relationship up?

Here is an example:

I create a new quote and select 'Active' as the `Status` and the `Event` as 'Golf'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done great

```
Quote -> bleongsTo -> Status 
Quote -> bleongsTo -> Event

Status -> hasMany -> Quote
Event -> hasMany -> Quote
```

if we convert it to OctoberCMS relations

```
// Quote
public $belongsTo = [
    'status' => ...
    'event' => ...
];

// Status
public $hasMany = [
    'quotes' => ...
];


// Event
public $hasMany = [
    'quotes' => ...
];
```

you can make relations like this

if any doubt please comment.